# gzipping powerpoint files not working

Tags: c#, gzip

I would like to know if it is possible to gzip a powerpoint file. the reason for me asking this question is because all of the article which I have found are gzipping a .txt and would like to know if its possible to gzip a .pptx.. through the use of c#.. the code below is what i am using

```
static void Main()
    {
    try
    {
        string anyString = File.ReadAllText("presentation.pptx");

        CompressStringToFile("new.gz", anyString);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Couldn't compress.
    }
    }

    public static void CompressStringToFile(string fileName, string value)
    {
    // A.
    // Write string to temporary file.
    string temp = Path.GetTempFileName();
    File.WriteAllText(temp, value);

    // B.
    // Read file into byte array buffer.
    byte[] b;
    using (FileStream f = new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Open))
    {
        b = new byte[f.Length];
        f.Read(b, 0, (int)f.Length);
    }


    using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
    {
        gz.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .pptx file (also .docx and .xlsx) is already zipped.  If you change the file extension to .zip and open the file you'll see the contents.

So, while you should be able to gzip one of these files, it's unlikely you'd see a great deal of further compression.

Comment: saying that i had a 1mb file and i was to gzip it it would not make much of a difference.

Comment: but say i wanted to still gzip the file how can i go about doing this

Comment: Ok, Instead of File.ReadAllText (.pptx is not a text file) I think you should open a FileStream on the .pptx file.  Go into a loop, reading chunks with fileStream.read() and writing those chunks into your GZipStream.